# Как получить строго возрастающую последовательность, удалив из массива не более одного элемента?

Tags: php, javascript, алгоритм

> Ответ можно написать и на javascript.

Учитывая последовательность целых чисел в виде массива, определите, можно ли получить строго возрастающую последовательность, удалив из массива не более одного элемента.

К примеру:

1. Для `$sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1]` вывод должен быть

   ```
   almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = false;
   ```
2. Для `$sequence = [1, 3, 2]` вывод должен быть

   ```
   almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = true;
   ```

Вы можете удалить 3 из массива, чтобы получить строго возрастающую последовательность [1, 2]. В качестве альтернативы вы можете удалить 2, чтобы получить строго возрастающую последовательность [1, 3].

3. Для `$sequence = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` вывод должен быть

   ```
   almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = true;
   ```

Возвращает `true`, если можно удалить один элемент из массива, чтобы получить строго возрастающую последовательность, иначе верните значение `false`.

Пытаюсь решить следующим путем:

```
function almostIncreasingSequence($sequence) {
    $r = 0;
    for ($i = 0, $prev = -1, $cnt = count($sequence)-2; $i < $cnt; $i ++)
    {
        if(!isset($sequence[$i]))
            continue;
        if ($sequence[$i] >= $sequence[$i+1])
        {
            $r ++;
            $i = $prev;
            unset($sequence[$i+1]);
        }
    }
    return $r < 1;
}

var_dump(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 3])); //true
var_dump(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2, 1])); //Должен быть false, вместо этого получаю бесконечный цикл
```

**Внимание вопрос:** Как правильно решить эту задачу ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479325/178988 - можно использовать тот же подход - префиикс и суффикс являются возрастающими последовательностями, а место стыка дополнительно проверить на удаление элемента (может быть лишний центральный, либо в отсутствии центрального один из крайних). Асимптотика линейная.

Comment: @Qwertiy OK,Спасибо  !

Comment: Запостил ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использую тот же подход, что и в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479325/178988 - префиикс и суффикс являются возрастающими последовательностями, а место стыка надо дополнительно проверить на удаление элемента (может быть лишний центральный, либо в отсутствии центрального один из крайних). Асимптотика линейная.

```js
function process(a) {
  var l, r, i;

  for (l = 0; a[l] < a[l+1]; ++l);
  if (l >= a.length - 1) return a;
  for (r = a.length-1; a[r-1] < a[r]; --r);

  function check(a, b) {
    return a == null || a < b || b == null;
  }

  switch (r-l) {
    case 1:
      if (check(a[l-1], a[r])) {
        i = l;
      } else if (check(a[l], a[r+1])) {
        i = r;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      if (check(a[l], a[r])) {
        i = l + 1;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
      break;
    default:
      return null;
  }
  
  a.splice(i, 1);
  return a;
}

console.log(process([1,2,3]))
console.log(process([1,2,3,0]))
console.log(process([9,1,2,3,0]))
console.log(process([1,2,9,3,4]))
console.log(process([1,2,9,0,3,4]))
console.log(process([]))
console.log(process([-1,0,-5]))
```

Comment: Да ,  swithch это что то :) ,люблю пользоваться им

Comment: Сделайте проверки на вот эти два случая 1 ) console.log(process([])) 2) console.log(process([-1,0,-5]))

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, пустой массив поправил, а во втором всё верно: `-5` убираем. остаётся `-1, 0` - возрастающая последовательность.

Comment: `[-1,0,0,-1]` по моему eто false случай.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, у меня в коде везде `<=`, а в твоём `<`. Если изменишь знак в 3 местах, станет как ты ожидаешь.

Comment: Я рассматриваю ваш ответ как потенциальный ответ.Пожалуйста протестируйте ваш код убрав все погрешности.Вeд он скорее всего понадобится другим людям.А я то eстественно смогу его подогнать под свой вопрос

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, да, я что-то не обратил внимание, что в вопросе требовалось строго возрастающую. Исправил.

Answer (score 1):

Решил таким образом:

> Если другой ответ будет более элегантным и оптимальнее то приму eго

```
function almostIncreasingSequence($sequence) {
    if(!$sequence)
        return NULL;
    $foundOne = false;

    for ($i = -1, $j = 0, $k = 1; $k < count($sequence); $k++)
    {
        $deleteCurrent = false;
        if ($sequence[$j] >= $sequence[$k])
        {
            if ($foundOne)
            {
                return false;
            }
            $foundOne = true;
            if ($k > 1 && $sequence[$i] >= $sequence[$k])
            {
                $deleteCurrent = true;
            }
        }
        if (!$foundOne)
        {
            $i = $j;
        }
        if (!$deleteCurrent)
        {
            $j = $k;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

var_dump(almostIncreasingSequence([1,3,2]));//true
var_dump(almostIncreasingSequence([1,3,2,1]));//false
var_dump(almostIncreasingSequence([2,1,2,3]));//true
```

Comment: Хм.. Вроде работает: http://ideone.com/2GkAvg, но меня что-то смущает независимое использование двух флагов.

Comment: @Qwertiy Люблю пользоваться флагами :)